# microprofile-config.properties as ConfigMap in Openliberty

Tags: kubernetes, jakarta-ee, configmap, open-liberty

[This example](https://openliberty.io/guides/kubernetes-microprofile-config.html#updating-kubernetes-resources) shows how to use `ConfigMaps` with openliberty.

The problem to me is that you have to create a section for the env variable in each of kubernetes deployment.

```
containers:
      - name: system-container
        image: system:1.0-SNAPSHOT
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9080
        # Set the environment variables
        env:
        - name: CONTEXT_ROOT
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: sys-app-root
              key: contextRoot
        - name: SYSTEM_APP_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: sys-app-credentials
              key: username
        - name: SYSTEM_APP_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: sys-app-credentials
              key: password
```

Wouldn't it be just easier to upload `microprofile-config.properties` as
a `ConfigMap` and mount it as volume to the right location?

Comment: Did the provided answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to create env part for each value. You can create your config map from `microprofile-config.properties` file and then just use `envFrom` to load all the key pairs like this:

```
      envFrom:
      - configMapRef:
          name: my-microprofile-config
```

But maybe I missed your real problem...

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using open-liberty I also think that creating your own config-map using `microprofile-config.properties` file will be good idea.

---

According to [this documentation](https://openliberty.io/blog/2021/03/31/microprofile-config-2.0.html):

> **MicroProfile Config** allows you to define configuration values, which are referred to as "config property" values, in a huge range of locations that are known as [ConfigSources](https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-config-2.0/microprofile-config-spec-2.0.html#configsource).

To load all the key pairs one can use `envForm` (just like @Gus suggested).

According to [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/):
One can use `envForm` to define all of the ConfigMap's data as container environment variables.

> The key from the ConfigMap becomes the environment variable name in the Pod.

[Here is the example of use ***envForm***](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#:%7E:text=apiVersion%3A%20v1%0Akind%3A%20Pod%0Ametadata%3A%0A%20%20name%3A%20dapi%2Dtest%2Dpod%0Aspec%3A%0A%20%20containers%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%2D%20name%3A%20test%2Dcontainer%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20image%3A%20k8s.gcr.io/busybox%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20command%3A%20%5B%20%22/bin/sh%22%2C%20%22%2Dc%22%2C%20%22env%22%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20envFrom%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2D%20configMapRef%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20special%2Dconfig%0A%20%20restartPolicy%3A%20Never):

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "env" ]
      envFrom:
      - configMapRef:
          name: special-config
  restartPolicy: Never
```

To load all the key pairs you need this scrap:

```yaml
      envFrom:
      - configMapRef:
          name: special-config
```

---

See also [this](https://openliberty.io/docs/22.0.0.1/external-configuration.html) and [this](https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-config-2.0/microprofile-config-spec-2.0.html) documentations.